# How to forward all requests to www subdomain including https requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

I have a VPS with a Rails 4 application running on Ubuntu, NginX and Unicorn.

As I want all pages to be SSL encrypted, all requests to `http://` are forwarded to `https://` which is working fine.

This is an excerpt of my NginX configuration:

```
http {

        ....

        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name example.com;
                rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }

        server {
                listen 443;
                server_name example.com;
                root /home/rails/public;
                index index.htm index.html;

                ssl on;
                ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example.com.key;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
                }

                location @app {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_pass http://app_server;
                 }
        }
}
```

How can I make it that all requests to `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are forwarded to `https://www.example.com`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess using a Rack middleware can solve this. Check this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

We use this in `apache2`:

```
<VirtualHost *80>
    ServerName frontlineutilities.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.frontlineutilities.co.uk 
</VirtualHost>
```

[Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

Having researched [how you'd achieve this in Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), I found this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org  www.example.org;
    ...
}
```

--

**Capturing Requests**

The reason I wrote this as an answer is because your choice is whether to use Middleware or the web server itself

Although I don't know the specifics, I *do* know that adding to the Rails middleware will eventually lead to bloat. I am a firm proponent of [modular programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) - and will gladly separate functionality into different parts of the stack

The problem you have is not really a `rails` one - it's a server issue (how to route all requests to `www.`). I would therefore highly recommend you focus on the server to get it sorted. As in the end, the sever is there to capture requests to your server IP & route them accordingly

I would start with the resources above & work to redirect in the server. It doesn't matter to rails whether you send a request to `www.` or the standard `domain`

Comment: Thanks for the nice write-up. I couldn't get this to work though which is probably due to my lack of experience in Apache & NginX.

Comment: Do you have any feedback? Errors / request issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to setup which redirects http://example.com or https://example.com to http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com

The following should do the redirect

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
} 
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Also you have change your original server_name to www.example.com
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It works for the normal `http://` domains when I add the line `rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;` to the first block (the one listening on port 80). When I add the same line to the second block as well, I get a `too many redirects` error in the browser, though. How can this be fixed?